# Problems using Check for C unit testing

Tags: c, unit-testing

Built check 0.9.14 using Visual Studio 2013 as per the instructions. This went well.

I am then attempting to link to the .lib and include the header in another C project (Again built by msvc 2013).

Here is my source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <check.h>

int main(void)
{
   printf("Hello World!\n");
   return 0;
 }
```

I'm getting various errors when compiling, all from check.h.

Most of them are C2059 syntax errors.
Here is the list:

```
C2059: syntax error : ')'
C2059: syntax error : ';'
C2061: syntax error : identifier 'pid'
C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'pid'
C2059: syntax error : 'type'
C2061: syntax error : identifier 'check_fork'
```

I cant find much help on this, any ideas?

Comment: I'm guessing the errors are in the `<check.h>` header file? Then you need to tell the author instead of asking us.

Answer (score 0):

add `typedef int pid_t` before including `check.h`